# Providing updated details to another answer [meta]

Tags: ros, meta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say that I came upon a question with an accepted, but rather old answer (from Hydro, for example). Is appropriate to provide another answer that only updates the old accepted answer? Or, should the accepted answer be edited? Something else?

I don't think that editing the accepted answer is the correct way to go about it, but I'm looking for clarification.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268894/providing-updated-details-to-another-answer-%5Bmeta%5D/) by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I don't think that editing the accepted answer is the correct way to go about it, [..]

Editing the answer to remove whatever was there - updating typically includes removing parts - is probably not very nice.

What could be acceptable is to post a new answer, and then edit the accepted one to *add* a note that there is a new answer. The note could be placed at the top of the original answer, to make sure it has maximum visibility.

Something like:

> Edit YYYY-MM-DD: see answer by @user_who_posted_new_answer for an updated answer.
>
> ---
>
> The original answer text ..

---

And with enough karma it's also possible to *unaccept* the answer and then accept the new one. Personally I would not do that, as it implies that the original poster accepted the new answer, which he hasn't (and with really old questions most likely never will do).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-16**:
I like the idea of appending the date and newer answer reference to the accepted answer. Thanks @gvdhoorn